# Expected varint not more than 10 bytes

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I am making an dynamic call (WPS request) to my internal geo-server and getting an json response. I am binding the resultant json in a mapbox layer, while doing so - am getting

> Error {message: 'Expected varint not more than 10 bytes'}

Json object has 10+ shapes with more than 10 attributes ;  am using react-map-gl library with axios for request. Need some pointer to fix this.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I get the same error when running my React project in VS Code but it doesn't happen in my production environment. Whenever it throws the error parts of the map don't load but it doesn't seem to break anything. I think it only happens when I'm running the debugger in VS Code.

Comment: @kbeeveer46 same here. Debug in VS code (Angular + Mapbox) throws the error and doesn't load/show certain tiles. Production build no issues. Very annoying as I am mostly in development mode 